# Aggregating Data in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, oracle9i

When looking at the picture in the link I need the Imploded Units to Average and the Exploded Units to Sum, I will attach my code below the Results shown below. I have been searching for an answer to this for a few days. I fear I may be trying to code over my head a little bit.

[image]

```
   SELECT A.to_load_id                                   AS "Cases", 
   A.from_qty - A.to_qty                          AS "Imploded Units", 
   ( A.from_qty - A.to_qty ) * Nvl(SUM(p.qty), 1) AS "Exploded Units", 
   A.wskusku                                      AS "Sku's", 
   A.wave                                         AS "Wave", 
   A.from_loc                                     AS "Processed Location", 
   A.free_form_text                               AS "Zone" ,

   FROM   audits A, 
   prepack P 
   WHERE  A.from_loc LIKE 'S%' 
   AND A.to_loc = A.from_loc 
   AND free_form_text IN ( '01', '02', '03', '04', 
                           '05', '06', '07', '08', 
                           '09', '10', '11', '12', 
                           '13', '14' ) 
   AND A.wskusku = p.sku (+) 
   AND A.from_load_id = '42419472' 
   AND A.wave in ('WC055193','','','','','','','','','')
   AND To_date(Substr(a.date_wms, 1, 12), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') >= 
       SYSDATE - 4 
   GROUP  BY A.to_load_id, 
      A.from_qty, 
      A.to_qty, 
      P.qty, 
      A.wskusku, 
      A.wave, 
      A.from_loc, 
      A.free_form_text
```

Comment: With this I receive multiple lines for A.to_load_id field. I essentially need to group the data by A.to_load_id with an Average in the Imploded Units and a Sum in the Exploded Units.

Comment: You neglected to mention your database system and version. We prefer text over images, where one cannot copy text.

Comment: The Database System is Oracle 9I(My apologies for not including it).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `avg()` / `sum()` and *not* `GROUP BY` columns that are involved in aggregates:

```
SELECT A.to_load_id                                    AS "Cases"
      ,avg(A.from_qty - A.to_qty)                      AS "Imploded Units"
      ,sum(A.from_qty - A.to_qty) * Nvl(SUM(P.qty), 1) AS "Exploded Units"
      ,A.wskusku                                       AS "Sku's"
      ,A.wave                                          AS "Wave"
      ,A.from_loc                                      AS "Processed Location"
      ,A.free_form_text                                AS "Zone"
FROM   audits A 
JOIN   prepack P ON P.sku (+) = A.wskusku
WHERE  A.from_loc LIKE 'S%' 
AND    A.to_loc = A.from_loc 
AND    A.free_form_text IN ( '01', '02', '03', '04', 
                           '05', '06', '07', '08', 
                           '09', '10', '11', '12', 
                           '13', '14' )
AND    A.from_load_id = '42419472'
AND    A.wave in ('WC055193','','','','','','','','','')
AND    To_date(Substr(A.date_wms, 1, 12), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') >= SYSDATE - 4
GROUP  BY A.to_load_id, 
      ,A.wskusku
      ,A.wave
      ,A.from_loc
      ,A.free_form_text
```

Not sure why you multiple the `"Exploded Units"`, but not the `"Imploded Units"`. I copied what you have there.

Comment: The Exploded Units is directly relational to the Imploded Units...1 Imploded Unit = 7 Exploded Units in this instance...you have set me on the right path....thank you so much...I will respond with any additional inquiries.